# How can i use my application with linphone-sdk-android for incoming calls to my freePBX accounts?

Tags: android, sip, linphone, freepbx, linphone-sdk

I developed a mobil app for Android phones.

And I used linphone-sdk-android-5.1.2.aar in this app.

My app is

linphone account to linphone account - perfect working

freePBX account to linphone account - perfect working

but

linphone account to freePBX account - not working

freePBX account to freePBX account - not working

for incoming call accept.

I think, linphone-android-sdk isn't accept third party accounts for incoming calls.

How can i use my application with linphone-sdk-android for incoming calls to my freePBX accounts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried a lot of tests and I found my problem. I changed my freePBX extensions chan pjsip to chan sip. It works fine.